# Please call CachedImageRenderer.Init method in a platform specific project to use FFImageLoading?

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios

When trying to use Xamarin FFImageLoading plugin on iOs I get this exception:

```
System.Exception: Please call CachedImageRenderer.Init method in a platform specific project to use FFImageLoading!
  at FFImageLoading.Forms.CachedImage.OnSourcePropertyChanged (Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject bindable, System.Object oldValue, System.Object newValue) [0x00007] in C:\projects\ffimageloading\source\FFImageLoading.Forms\CachedImage.cs:133 
  at Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject.SetValueActual (Xamarin.Forms.BindableProperty property, Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject+BindablePropertyContext context, System.Object value, System.Boolean currentlyApplying, Xamarin.Forms.Internals.SetValueFlags attributes, System.Boolean silent) [0x00120] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\BindableObject.cs:625 
  at Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject.SetValueCore (Xamarin.Forms.BindableProperty property, System.Object value, Xamarin.Forms.Internals.SetValueFlags attributes, Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject+SetValuePrivateFlags privateAttributes) [0x0015b] in D:\a\1\s\Xam
arin.Forms.Core\BindableObject.cs:417 
  at Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject.SetValue (Xamarin.Forms.BindableProperty property, System.Object value, System.Boolean fromStyle, System.Boolean checkAccess) [0x0003d] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\BindableObject.cs:573 
  at Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject.SetValue (Xamarin.Forms.BindableProperty property, System.Object value) [0x00000] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\BindableObject.cs:99 
  at FFImageLoading.Forms.CachedImage.set_Source (Xamarin.Forms.ImageSource value) [0x00000] in C:\projects\ffimageloading\source\FFImageLoading.Forms\CachedImage.cs:173 
  at Demo.MainViewModel..ctor () [0x0001f] in <4cd5393447f94973bb9eef7c0de8880d>:0 
  at FullCameraApp.CameraPage.getLayoutImage (System.Int32 index) [0x00001] in <4cd5393447f94973bb9eef7c0de8880d>:0 
  at FullCameraApp.CameraPage..ctor (ScoreScan.webServices.WebServices webServices, System.Collections.Generic.List`1[T] imageBytesList) [0x0060b] in <4cd5393447f94973bb9eef7c0de8880d>:0 
  at ScoreScan.App..ctor () [0x0
0025] in <4cd5393447f94973bb9eef7c0de8880d>:0 
  at ScoreScan.iOS.AppDelegate.FinishedLaunching (UIKit.UIApplication app, Foundation.NSDictionary options) [0x0000d] in <4cd5393447f94973bb9eef7c0de8880d>:0 
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) UIKit.UIApplication.UIApplicationMain(int,string[],intptr,intptr)
  at UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.IntPtr principal, System.IntPtr delegate) [0x00005] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.14.0.14/src/Xamarin.iOS/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:79 
  at UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.String principalClassName, System.String delegateClassName) [0x0002c] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.14.0.14/src/Xamarin.iOS/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:63 
  at ScoreScan.iOS.Application.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00001] in <4cd5393447f94973bb9eef7c0de8880d>:0 
2018-10-08 19:47:10.229 ScoreScan.iOS[324:13181] Unhandled managed exception:
Please call CachedImageRenderer.Init method in a platform specific project to use FFImageLoading! (System.Exception)
  at FFImageLoading.Forms.CachedImage.OnSourcePropertyChanged (Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject bindable, System.Object oldValue, System.Object newValue) [0x00007] in C:\projects\ffimageloading\source\FFImageLoading.Forms\CachedImage.cs:133 
  at Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject.SetValueActual (Xamarin.Forms.BindableProperty property, Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject+BindablePropertyContext context, System.Object value, System.Boolean currentlyApplying, Xamarin.Forms.Internals.SetValueFlags attributes, System.Boolean silent) [0x00120] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\BindableObject.cs:625 
  at Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject.SetValueCore (Xamarin.Forms.BindableProperty property, System.Object value, Xamarin.Forms.Internals.SetValueFlags attributes, Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject+SetValuePrivateFlags privateAttributes) [0x0015b] in D:\a
\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\BindableObject.cs:417 
  at Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject.SetValue (Xamarin.Forms.BindableProperty property, System.Object value, System.Boolean fromStyle, System.Boolean checkAccess) [0x0003d] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\BindableObject.cs:573 
  at Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject.SetValue (Xamarin.Forms.BindableProperty property, System.Object value) [0x00000] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\BindableObject.cs:99 
  at FFImageLoading.Forms.CachedImage.set_Source (Xamarin.Forms.ImageSource value) [0x00000] in C:\projects\ffimageloading\source\FFImageLoading.Forms\CachedImage.cs:173 
  at Demo.MainViewModel..ctor () [0x0001f] in <4cd5393447f94973bb9eef7c0de8880d>:0 
  at FullCameraApp.CameraPage.getLayoutImage (System.Int32 index) [0x00001] in <4cd5393447f94973bb9eef7c0de8880d>:0 
  at FullCameraApp.CameraPage..ctor (ScoreScan.webServices.WebServices webServices, System.Collections.Generic.List`1[T] imageBytesList) [0x0060b] in <4cd5393447f94973bb9eef7c0de8880d>:0 
  at ScoreScan.App..ctor
ktrace:
```

How Can I solve this exception?

Comment: What is your question?  The error message is telling you to do X - are you?  I can't say since you didn't bother to post any code.

Comment: @Jason, the exception says call "CachedImageRenderer.Init", but I didnt know where to place that, "hashimks" shared the documentation, and answered my question, it was not necesary to share any code.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Call CachedImageRenderer.Init after global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(); in FinishedLaunching method present in AppDelegate.cs file of iOS project.

It clearly mention that you need to call Init method inside this. The details will be given in the github repository of FFImageLoading plugin

It is mentioned in the following [link](https://github.com/luberda-molinet/FFImageLoading/wiki/Xamarin.Forms-API)

Comment: Thanks, that worked!!, Could also share the link to the github repository where is that described?